# I'm trying to initialize my accounts and the tx goes through but it says the account doesn't exist when i retrieve info from it

Tags: pda, initialize

Essentially all the lists are the same, but when I call the bluelist account I get

"Error: Account does not exist HkBnFqgNQfWisvKkDwSbUzE2EJ3jriQHY64H4t3EjjeM"

this error happens on every account. Any help is appreciated

```
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    let mut bluelist_raw = ctx.accounts.bluelist.load_init()?;
    let mut redlist_raw = ctx.accounts.redlist.load_init()?;
    let mut purplelist_raw = ctx.accounts.purplelist.load_init()?;
    let blue = &mut ctx.accounts.blue;
    let red = &mut ctx.accounts.red;
    let purple = &mut ctx.accounts.purple;
    let fees = &mut ctx.accounts.fees;

    let mut bluelist = bluelist_raw.deref_mut();
    let mut redlist = redlist_raw.deref_mut();
    let mut purplelist = purplelist_raw.deref_mut();

    bluelist.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    redlist.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    purplelist.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;

    blue.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    red.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    purple.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    fees.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;


    bluelist.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("bluelist").unwrap();
    redlist.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("redlist").unwrap();
    purplelist.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("purplelist").unwrap();
    blue.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("blue").unwrap();
    red.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("red").unwrap();
    purple.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("purple").unwrap();
    fees.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("fees").unwrap();


    bluelist.counter = 0;
    redlist.counter = 0;
    purplelist.counter = 0;

    bluelist.total = 0;
    redlist.total = 0;
    purplelist.total = 0;


    Ok(())
}
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"fees",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        rent_exempt = enforce,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Fees>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]    
    pub fees : Account<'info, Fees>,
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"blue",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Blue>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]    
    pub blue : Account<'info, Blue>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"red",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Red>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]  
    pub red : Account<'info, Red>,
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"purple",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Purple>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]  
    pub purple : Account<'info, Purple>,

    #[account(
        zero,
        seeds = [b"bluelist",user.key().as_ref()],
        owner = *program_id,
        bump
    )]
    
    pub bluelist : AccountLoader<'info, Bluelist>,
    #[account(
        zero,
        seeds = [b"redlist",user.key().as_ref()],
        owner = *program_id,
        bump
    )]
    pub redlist : AccountLoader<'info, Redlist>,
    #[account(
        zero,
        seeds = [b"purplelist",user.key().as_ref()],
        owner = *program_id,
        bump
    )]
    pub purplelist : AccountLoader<'info, Purplelist>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[zero_copy]
pub struct ListEntry {
pub entry: Pubkey,
pub deposit: u64,
}

#[account]
pub struct Fees {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub bump: u8,
}

#[account]
pub struct Blue {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub bump: u8,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]

pub struct Bluelist {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub bluelist_entry: [ListEntry; 25000],
pub counter: u64,
pub total: u64,
pub bump: u8,
}



#[derive(Accounts)]

pub struct AddBluelistEntry<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub bluelist: AccountLoader<'info, Bluelist>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user : Signer<'info>,
#[account(mut)]
pub blue : Account<'info,Blue>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Red {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub bump: u8,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]

pub struct Redlist {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub redlist_entry: [ListEntry; 25000],
pub counter: u64,
pub total: u64,
pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AddRedlistEntry<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub redlist: AccountLoader<'info, Redlist>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user : Signer<'info>,
#[account(mut)]
pub red : Account<'info,Red>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Purple {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub bump: u8,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]

pub struct Purplelist {
pub authority: Pubkey,
pub winners: [ListEntry; 100000],
pub counter: u64,
pub total: u64,
pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Rewarding<'info> {
pub blue : Account<'info, Blue>,
pub red : Account<'info, Red>,
pub purple : Account<'info, Purple>,
pub fees : Account<'info, Fees>,

#[account(mut)]
pub bluelist: AccountLoader<'info, Bluelist>,
#[account(mut)]
pub redlist: AccountLoader<'info, Redlist>,
#[account(mut)]
pub purplelist: AccountLoader<'info, Purplelist>,

}



#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Claiming<'info> {

#[account(mut)]
pub purple : Account<'info, Purple>,

#[account(mut)]
pub purplelist: AccountLoader<'info, Purplelist>,

#[account(mut)]
pub user : Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FeeClaim<'info>{
#[account(mut)]
pub fees: Account<'info, Fees>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user: Signer<'info>,
}
```

This is the testing code

```
  const foo = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const newUser = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();


  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const [blue] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('blue'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(), 
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [red] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('red'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [purple] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('purple'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [bluelist] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('bluelist'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [redlist] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('redlist'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [purplelist] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('purplelist'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [fees] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('fees'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );

    const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
      user: foo.publicKey,
      fees: fees,
      blue: blue,
      red: red,
      purple: purple,
      bluelist: bluelist,
      redlist: redlist,
      purplelist: purplelist,
      authority: foo.publicKey,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      
      }).signers([foo]).instruction();
    console.log("tx", tx);

    const blueAccount = await program.account.blue.fetch(blue);
    console.log("blue", blueAccount);
    
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test you need to send the transaction, currently you've only build the instruction.

You'll first need to airdrop SOL to the newly generated `foo` keypair so it can pay for the transaction

```
   const foo = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

   before(async () => {
        const transactionSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
            foo.publicKey,
            1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        )

        const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } =
            await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

        await connection.confirmTransaction(
            {
            blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight,
            signature: transactionSignature,
            },
            "confirmed"
        )
    })
```

Then you can send the transaction like this

```
const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
      user: foo.publicKey,
      fees: fees,
      blue: blue,
      red: red,
      purple: purple,
      bluelist: bluelist,
      redlist: redlist,
      purplelist: purplelist,
      authority: foo.publicKey,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      
      }).transaction();

await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [foo])
```

Comment: appreciate the help, i can't get the connection to airdrop me sol to a newkey gen though

Comment: If you're using the default test file Anchor generates for you, you can get the connection like this:  
`const connection = program.provider.connection`. 

Add it below the line that Anchor generates which looks like this:  `const program = anchor.workspace.YourProgram as Program<YourProgram>`

Comment: thanks that worked1 now i need to figure out the bugs in my code